# React native IOS app become slow with usage

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am facing an issue. Android App is working fine. In the IOS app, there is an issue. If I use my app for a least five minutes continuously.

**The app becomes very slow; CPU usage is about 80% and memory is above 200MB and sometimes the app crashes.**

I am trying to debug but there is no warning or memory leaked problem showing. how can I solve this?
I am getting videos from the camera roll and displaying them in different tabs.
Here I am sharing some screenshots of the app.
Here you can check that first the memory usage was 92 then 113 and then 130.
Here is a link to a Facebook post containing

- screenshots of the app
- check that first the memory usage was 92 then 113 and then 130.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/1525443277786007/permalink/2687836244880032/
Here is the list of dependencies I am using.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/cookies": "^5.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^4.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.19",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.19",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
    "@tuofeng/react-native-system-notification": "^0.3.0",
    "curved-bottom-navigation-bar": "^1.0.6",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-admob-native-ads": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-animated-loader": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-device-info": "^6.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-tab-view-viewpager-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.9.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
```

I am using

- XCode 12.3
- Node Version 15
- MacOS Big Sur
- I am using iPhone 6 to test the app.

In the project I am getting some videos from cameraRoll and display them in different tabs.

Comment: hie Aftab!   nice question: can you elaborate a bit more that how you did the debug?

did you try using Flipper  to see the cpu performance and logs?

do share the RN version and tell how you are caching the Data and the post does not show what type of project it is!

Comment: I have edited my post. I am new to react with native ios. I am using Xcode debugger.

Comment: I do not see a package that is handling permissions of reading and writing!

Comment: I used to react-native-permissions. and there is no issue with permissions. it is saving, reading, and deleting from the camera roll.